# Extract waymo dataset to jpeg image files

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, jpeg, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to extract waymo tensorrecord (tensorflow) based dataset to pictrue files.

I've tried the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
FILENAME = 'D:\\waymo3\\waymo_open_dataset_v_1_2_0_individual_files\\training\\segment-15832924468527961_1564_160_1584_160_with_camera_labels.tfrecord'
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FILENAME, compression_type='')
i=0
for data in dataset:
    print(dir(data))
    with open('C:\\Users\\my_user\\Desktop\\extracted_pic\\'+str(i)+'.jpeg', 'ab') as the_file:
        the_file.write(data.numpy())
    i+=1
```

Unfortunately, it creates a folder with unreadable jpeg.
I believe the dataset of waymo is saved in JPEG.
Therefore I can't understand what is my mistake.

As one sees, I've tried to open the folder in windows (10)